# How to calculate a derivative row in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How do I calculate the last row (Avg Spend) in SSRS?  This row is a derivative of the first two rows (Purchase Amt / # of Transactions)?  I can't pre-calculate this value when building the dataset because I have many products in my list and I am using multiple-checkboxes.  What I am trying to accomplish is I want to allow the user to see the Avg Spend of the different combinations of products they selected in the parameters.

[Picture of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBJvw.png)

Comment: The xpression is a simple calculation as you showed in your question so I'm not sure what the problem is? What have you tried? What does you report design look like at the moment?

Comment: If your data set looks like that.. why not just put that in a details row in a tablix and then just calculate the average spend at the group level?? Looks pretty straight forward.. can't see what the issue is